# Loading with AJAX and going to anchor in loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, anchor

I'm building a website to organize comics collections.

So you have on the left a list of yours comics and if you click on one of them, the page with the details about that comic is loaded on the right with AJAX with the jQuery `load()` function.

I don't have a page for every comic but for every serie (one for all the "Walking dead", one for all the "Spiderman"....) so on every page that can be a lot of different comics.

However when clicking on a specific comic I not only want to load the correct page but also to go at the correct position in this page.

I have anchors in every page (#i12,#i13 with a unique number each time).

How can I, after the content is loaded using AJAX, go to the correct anchor ? I tried to dynamically modify the page URL (adding a #i12 at the end) but without success.

I was using `document.location.hash`, bad idea ?

---

A very simple example : when clicking on the link the page is loaded into the div and I would like the page to scroll to the anchor `#i120`

Main page :

```
<div id="list">
<a href="test.php#i120">Go to num 120</a>
</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$("a").live('click',function (event)
{
    $("#Content").load(this.href);

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Page Test.php :

```
<div id="i1">Text1</div>
...
...
<div id="i120">Text120</div>
```

Comment: Can you possibly post the jQuery you're working with? And a representative excerpt of your html?

Comment: Extremely simplified code posted.

Comment: In which case I'd tend to agree with [@tandu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056339/loading-with-ajax-and-going-to-anchor-in-loaded-content/4056439#4056439), below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's get rid of invalid IDs, they can't start with a number until HTML5, I'd prefix your IDs with something like `id="nav1"`.

That part is cleanup, what you can do for the scrolling is this:

```
$("a").live('click', function(event) {
    var hash = this.hash;
    $("#Content").load(this.href, function() {
      document.location.hash = hash;
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

That'll run once the content is loaded, so there's something to scroll to.  That approach instantly goes there, so to animate it...that's easy enough as well:

```
$("a").live('click', function(event) {
    var hash = this.hash;
    $("#Content").load(this.href, function() {
      var st = $(hash).scrollTop();
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: st }, 200); //200ms duration
    });
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

We're storing `this.hash` as a variable because inside that callback, `this` will refer to the `#Content` element, not the anchor we clicked on.

Comment: Thanks. Invalid ID corrected. In practice it wasn't invalid (ie : #comic120) but I oversimplified it in the question....

Answer (score 2):

[Jquery ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) is probably your best bet.

Otherwise I would suggest having some invisible links on the page (like <a href="#1" id="link1"></a>) and then after the ajax completes and you have the id # you run:

```
$("#link" + idnumber).click();
```

Simple, but very effective.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something that does not use any external script but I will look at it.