# How to make a dynamic php website with permanent links?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

So i have a problem, I never did this before.

```
I have this website http://82.196.14.71/obrigatorionaover/ .
```

I want to generate ajax webpages but I want permanent links too for the browser history.

This is the body of the first page (releituras.php):

```
<body> 
 <?php 
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $path .= "/obrigatorionaover/php/nav.php";
  include_once($path);
 ?>


<div id="float">
 //this is a connect
 <?php 
  $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $path .= "/obrigatorionaover/xxxxxxxxxxxx.php";
  include_once($path);
 ?>

 <?php
  try {
   $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM sessoes ORDER BY id DESC');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo '<div  style="background-image:url('."http://localhost:8888/obrigatorionaover/".$row["img"].')" class="rect sessao" id=sessao'.$row["id"].'>'.'<h3 class="titulo">'.$row["numero_sessao"].'</h3>'.'<p class="descricao">'.$row["descricao"].'</p>'.'</div>';
    }
  } catch(PDOException $ex) {
     echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
    }
?>

</div>
 <script src="/obrigatorionaover/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I clean the div float and insert new content dynamically like this, (sessao.php is similar to the query from releituras.php)

```
function sessao(data){
 $("#float").html("");
 $.get("/obrigatorionaover/php/sessao.php?id=1").done(function(data) {
  $("#float").append(data);
 });
}
```

The url in the browser doesn't change, it is possible to change the url dynamically without changing the content?

The browser history doesn't change either (I know I can inject it but i don't have valid physic php page). How can I inject it? Should I create physic php pages automatically  when inserting information into the database?

Can I have something like virtual php pages? If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need - is to use HTML anchors together with ajax navigation.
When you load something with ajax, modify anchor. This will not reload page, but will give you really new `window.location`.
When page is loaded without ajax, parse that anchor (if exists) to determine what ajax page to display.
That is basic idea, a direction for your thoughts since I do not know the details of your project implementation.

[Loading with AJAX and going to anchor in loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056339/loading-with-ajax-and-going-to-anchor-in-loaded-content)

Comment: This is a academic project. I define how I want to do the implementation so I'm looking for good practices :).

I have a problem with that when I use,
`document.location = "php/sessao.php?id=1";`
suddenly only sessao.php content is loaded and I lose the rest of the information (head,nav...). I want to have a direct link like this but load the code of sessao.php into releituras.php.